# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'init_command'

Tags: python, django, swagger

I got this problem when trying to include swagger in django:

```py
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url

from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view
from index import views

schema_view = get_swagger_view(title='API')
urlpatterns = [

    #path('', views.index),

    path('img', views.add_image),
    path('valider', views.valider),
    path('all', views.get_all_image),
    path('docs/', schema_view),
    path('<str:idd>', views.get_image),
]
```

Comment: can you post the entire traceback in the question?

Comment: http://dpaste.com/2AYT5ZX